# Assigning the filename and sheet name to (multiple) observations in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, rbind, do.call, merging-data

I have written a function that, after giving the direction of the folder, takes all the excel files inside it and merges them into a data frame with some modest modifications.

Yet I have two small things I would like to add but struggle with:

1. Each file has a country code in the name, and I would like the function to create an additional column in the data frame, "Country", where each observation would be assigned such country code. **name example: BGR_CO2_May12**
2. Each file is composed of many sheets, with each sheet representing the year; these sheets are also called by these years. I would like the function to create another column, "Year", where each observation would be assigned the name of the sheet that it comes from.

Is there a neat way to do it? Possibly without modifying the current function?

```
multmerge_xls_TEST <- function(mypath2) {

library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(XLConnect)
library(XLConnectJars)
library(stringr)

# This function gets the list of files in a given folder

re_file <- ".+\\.xls.?"
testFiles <- list.files(path       = mypath2, 
                        pattern    = re_file, 
                        full.names = TRUE)

# This function rbinds in a single dataframe the content of multiple sheets in the same workbook 
# (assuming that all the sheets have the same column types)
# It also removes the first sheet (no data there)

rbindAllSheets <- function(file) {
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
    removeSheet(wb, sheet = 1)
    sheets <- getSheets(wb)
    do.call(rbind,
            lapply(sheets, function(sheet) {
                           readWorksheet(wb, sheet)
            })
    )
}

# Getting a single dataframe for all the Excel files and cutting out the unnecessary variables

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(testFiles, rbindAllSheets))
result <- result[,c(1,2,31)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a wrapper around `readWorksheet()`. This would store the file name into the variable `Country` and the sheet name into `Year`. You would need to do some regex on the file though to get the code only.

You could also skip the wrapper and simply add the `mutate()` line within your current function. Note this uses the `dplyr` package, which you already have referenced.

```
read_worksheet <- function(sheet, wb, file) {

  readWorksheet(wb, sheet) %>%
    mutate(Country = file,
           Year = sheet)

}
```

So then you could do something like this within the function you already have.

```
rbindAllSheets <- function(file) {
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
    removeSheet(wb, sheet = 1)
    sheets <- getSheets(wb)
    do.call(rbind,
            lapply(sheets, read_worksheet, wb = wb, file = file)
    )
}
```

As another note, `bind_rows()` is another `dplyr` function which can take the place of your `do.call(rbind, ...)` calls.

```
bind_rows(lapply(sheets, read_worksheet, wb = wb, file = file))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great!

In the end to get the country code in the column "Country" I used the following line of code:

df$Country <- substr(df$Country, 8, 10)

,where 8 is the first character you want to extract
and 10 is the last character you want to extract
(these will depend on the name of the folder that the merged files are in)